# Subsequence in MySQL/CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

In my mysql table I have a field which is a 4 letter Myers-Briggs personality type. I would like to search through the table and match when the personality type matches the one in the query by having 2 aspects in common. The way I understand this, it is really just finding the longest common subsequence of the two and testing that it is >= 2

Example:

'ISTJ' would match with 'INFJ', because the length of the common subsequence is 'IJ' >= 2

and

'ISTJ' would not match with 'INFP', because the length of the common subsequence is 'I' <= 2

Is there a way to do this in a mysql query? I am using CakePHP for the querying, so if you know how to do this with Cake that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Myer-Briggs personality types are positional.  This means that you can compare character by character.

Here is one method, where you just have to put in the comparison string once:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (case when substring(t.MyerBriggs, 1, 1) = substring(const.comp, 1, 1)
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as MB1,
             (case when substring(t.MyerBriggs, 2, 1) = substring(const.comp, 2, 1)
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as MB2,
             (case when substring(t.MyerBriggs, 3, 1) = substring(const.comp, 3, 1)
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as MB3,
             (case when substring(t.MyerBriggs, 4, 1) = substring(const.comp, 4, 1)
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as MB4
      from t cross join
           (select 'INFJ' as comp) const
     )
where (MB1+MB2+MB3+MB4) >= 2
```

You can actually simplify this in MySQL as:

```
      select t.*
      from t cross join
           (select 'INFJ' as comp) const
      where (if(substring(t.MyerBriggs, 1, 1) = substring(const.comp, 1, 1), 1, 0) +
             if(substring(t.MyerBriggs, 2, 1) = substring(const.comp, 2, 1), 1, 0) +
             if(substring(t.MyerBriggs, 3, 1) = substring(const.comp, 3, 1), 1, 0) +
             if(substring(t.MyerBriggs, 4, 1) = substring(const.comp, 4, 1), 1, 0)
            ) >= 2
```

Comment: +1 Probably negligibly less efficient to execute than my suggestion, but much easier to use, and requires no structure change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the Myers-Briggs thingy properly, there are two possibilities for each of the four categorisation axis, and the order of the letters is constant (and therefore carries no meaning).

In this case, you could use four two-state columns like the below, instead of one string:

```
CREATE TABLE profile (
    user_id INT,
    EI ENUM ('E', 'I'),
    SN ENUM ('S', 'N'),
    TF ENUM ('T', 'F'),
    JP ENUM ('J', 'P')
);
```

Profile 'ISTJ' would be inserted like this:

```
INSERT INTO profile VALUE (1, 'I', 'S', 'T', 'J');
```

Matching with profile 'INFJ' would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE
   (EI = 'I') + (SN = 'N') + (TF = 'F') + (JP = 'J') >= 2
```

Comment: Your final query has a problem.  Booleans in MySQL are represented as bits, not integers.  So, when you add them together, the only possible values are "0" and "1" -- the final `where` condition will always fail.  The easiest way to convert them to numbers is to use `case` or `if` statements.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I'm not sure I understand, it seems to be working fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f5b23/3 But you are right, it is more logical (and less hackish) to use a `IF` here.

Comment: . . That is weird.  When I tried it in SQLFiddle it didn't work.  Makes more sense, though, that it does.  I probably had some error in my test.